# What is the best multiple file JavaScript / Flash file uploader?

Tags: javascript, ajax, flash, file-upload, multifile-uploader

Specifically, I'm looking for a client-side, JavaScript and / or Flash based multiple file uploader.  The closest thing I've found is [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/).  Anyone have experience with it?  If not, what else is out there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yahoo's [YUI Uploader](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/uploader/uploader-dd.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 10):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is a jQuery / Flash hybrid (if you don't feel like adding in YUI just to handle uploads).

[Demo](http://www.uploadify.com/demo/)

[How to implement](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)

Comment: @slotishtype So sorry.  I'm sure if you could elaborate, other devs would appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah.  It looks like Uploadify kinda sucks now (not sure what's happened in the last 2 years).  I would recommend Plupload now (see the answer that lists it as a link)

Comment: Agree, it also has a bunch of issues when trying to use in IE9

Comment: I always get HTTP 302 error in OSX Safari/Firefox and randomly on windows FF. Not reliable at all. I'm looking for a replacement for uploadify.

Answer (score 6):

[SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/) is probably the leading "competitor" to that.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatives to SWFUpload:

- [YUI Uploader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/uploader/)
- [jqUploader](http://www.pixeline.be/experiments/jqUploader/) (jQuery plugin)
- [Flash/AJAX File Upload w/ Progress Server Control](http://weblogs.asp.net/jstengel/archive/2008/04/25/flash-file-upload-server-control.aspx) (ASP .NET based)

Answer (score 4):

[Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) seems to be interesting...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a new entry into this field is 'jQuery file upload':

[Wiki / documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)

[Demo page](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 2):

Agile Uploader now supports multiple files as of version 2.0. 
http://www.shift8creative.com/projects/agile-uploader/index.html

Here's a direct link to a demo:
http://www.shift8creative.com/agile-uploader/examples/all_files.php

It allows all types of files and can actually resize images before upload to help save on bandwidth costs and server processing power.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [FancyUpload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/) plenty of times and it's absolutely fantastic. The only problem (but this is true for most flash uploaders, I guess) is session handling - if you're using sessions you're going to have to pass along the session ID to the flash file and back again.

[digitarald](http://digitarald.de/) (the author) has a new version of FancyUpload in beta now that works with Flash 10 (something a lot of the other uploaders don't). According to him it should be very simple to upgrade from FancyUpload2 to the new version, once it's released.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Gears solution with client-side image resizing](http://bitbucket.org/kmike/gearsuploader/) (mine, sorry for advertisment)

Comment: ad is relevant & useful until it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

[Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) worked for me for simple drag-and-drop functionality that degrades gracefully. Very easy to set up.