# How can I detect if an ActiveX control is loaded?

Tags: javascript, activex

I would like to integrate the Aurigma image uploader (http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/) on a website.

On Internet Explorer the control is an ActiveX control which issues a security prompt prior to the first installation.

To give the user instructions about how to react to this security warning I'd like to display an information window. I want to display this window only the control is *not* loaded.

```
  if (controlIsNotLoaded()) {
    doSomething()
  }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using a Flash uploader (with HTML backup) in preference to custom ActiveX controls. User acceptance is much, much higher and you won't be asking people to compromise security by trusting a new third-party plugin. Aurigma certainly has had multiple vulnerabilities in the past; there's no way I'd let it run on my machine. Also there is no built-in HTML fallback so you could only offer it as a optional extra upload mechanism.

Comment: @bobince: Thanks for the advice. I'd be much happier to use a flash based uploader. Is there one that you can recommend?

Comment: Some suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207298/what-is-the-best-multiple-file-javascript-flash-file-uploader

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have the id of the object tag (if it is coming from that) then test for the *object* attribute of the element against null.

```
function controlNotLoaded()
{
     var obj = document.getElementById("controlId");
     return (obj.object == null);
}
```

If you are using new ActiveXObject then it will throw an exception. Of course this will only tell you if the control isn't able to be created, not necessarily why.