# asp.net mvc jquery checking size on file upload

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Is there any way to check the size of the file when it is about to be uploaded with jquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with jQuery...or with JavaScript at all :)  Mainly for security reasons you can't allowed to do most things with files (at least using *only* JavaScript).

However there are non-pure-JS alternatives that may be an option, like [SWF Upload](http://www.swfupload.org/), [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), [fancyupload](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/), etc.
[There's a question here with a decent list of alternatives available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207298/what-is-the-best-multiple-file-javascript-flash-file-uploader).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the jQuery Uploadify plugin. It can check file sizes, but it uses flash internally to get this info.