# Upload file and ajax/jquery fails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to add a file upload function to a contact form, but it won't work for some reason. The upload script works fine by itself, but when I add it to the contact code, the jquery script makes it fail.

As you can tell, I am by no means an expert.

**pontact.php**

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#contact_form').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            var post_url = form.attr('action');
            var post_data = form.serialize();
            $('#loader', form).html('<img src="loader.gif" /> Please Wait...');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: post_url, 
                data: post_data,
                success: function(msg) {
                    $(form).fadeOut(500, function(){
                        form.html(msg).fadeIn();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
        <div>
             <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
             <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1" />
        </div>
        <div>
             <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
             <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="2" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
        </div>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="512000" />
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
</div>
        <div id="loader">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Process.php**

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/download/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you cant upload a file using ajax,( [Why can't I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595049/why-cant-i-upload-files-asynchronously) )

but there are a few techinques, including iframes or flash plugins you could use

- [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)
- [What is the best multiple file JavaScript / Flash file uploader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207298/what-is-the-best-multiple-file-javascript-flash-file-uploader)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

File upload doesnt work via jQuery even if you call `form.serialize()`.

You can achieve the same effect via hacks like using iFrames (good [article](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/) here on this) or Flash based uploaders like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).