# how to enable multiple image file selection in IE in php html?

Tags: php, html, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTML5 input type file's multiple attribute not working in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987936/html5-input-type-files-multiple-attribute-not-working-in-ie)

i can able to upload multiple images in firefox, but in IE i can able to upload only one image

```
<form id="imageUploadForm" action="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php/product/UploadImages/<?php echo $uploadFolder;?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" > <input name="userfile[]" id="userfile" type="file" multiple /> <input name="" id="id_uploadbtn" type="submit" class="button" value="Upload" /> </form>
```

Comment: @naveen: You are invited to do some little research before you ask a question your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5987954/538866

Basically, IE8 and down does not support HTML5. This means the `multiple` part of your form is not recognized by Internet Explorer.

Comment: Is there any possible way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sadly, you cannot solve it so that <=IE8 recognizes `multiple`, but you can take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207298/what-is-the-best-multiple-file-javascript-flash-file-uploader?rq=1

Comment: @JonasG.Drange Why not close as dupe when the answer is already somewhere else?

Comment: I am trying to earn the rep, but my day job is in the way. I can flag it if that would help you close it.